# How to filter sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with this one.
How do i get a search to show results only  if "mail"field is not blank

```
 $fetch = mysql_query("
         SELECT * FROM student 
         WHERE class REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR week REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR name REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR f_name REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR avg1 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR avgf1 REGEXP '^$param'  
         OR avg2 REGEXP '^$param'
         OR avgf2 REGEXP '^$param'
         OR addr1 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR ex11 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR ex12 REGEXP '^$param'
         OR ex13 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR ex21 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR ex22 REGEXP '^$param'
         OR ex23 REGEXP '^$param' 
         OR addr2 REGEXP '^$param' 
         ORDER BY class DESC ");
```

Tanks!

Comment: and your sql is for???

Comment: Put all `OR`ed conditions in parentheses and add `AND mail IS NOT NULL AND mail <>''`

Comment: I´m a newbe in sql peterm, could you please give me an example on what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM student 
 WHERE (class REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR week REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR name REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR f_name REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR avg1 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR avgf1 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR avg2 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR avgf2 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR addr1 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex11 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex12 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex13 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex21 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex22 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR ex23 REGEXP '^$param' 
    OR addr2 REGEXP '^$param')
   AND mail IS NOT NULL 
   AND mail <> ''
 ORDER BY class DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ba94/2)** demo